# Understanding the space defined by a 2 dimensional vector

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems

I was watching a 3b1b video when he explained the relationship between a 1*2 matrix and a 2-dimensional vector, now he talks about how we can Interpret a 2-dimensional vector as a tilted number line, however, I am new to linear Algebra and I would like to know how is this space created by the 2-dimensional vector "tilted number line (1 dimensional)" defined in the math world, I would like to see some explanation of how this new space works

[image]

this vector is seen as a space where the 2-dimensional space is transformed with the 1*2 matrix

I think this space is a line defined by u, or is there any other explanation related to vector spaces?

Comment: I find this hard to understand. A $1\times 2$ matrix (as opposed to a $2\times 1$ matrix, which we commonly call a vector) represents a linear map $T$ from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$. $T(x)$ is the dot product of $x$ with the vector $v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}$, and so can be interpreted as giving the $\sqrt5$ times the signed length of the projection of $x$ on $v$. I cannot decipher the picture you posted.

Comment: @TedShifrin the line of symmetry tells that the projection of "i hat" onto u is the same as the x component of u and the same thing with j hat

Comment: Oh, silly me. They are using the vector $u=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix}$. I fixated on a different vector. Yes, $u\cdot x$ gives the first coordinate of $x$. The one-dimensional space spanned by $u$ is indeed that line. I'm not sure what more you're trying to say/see here.

Comment: @TedShifrin my question if is there a  rigorous definition for $\mathbb{R}$-space defined by u?

Comment: Of course, it's the subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ spanned by $u$. Have you studied subspaces, linear independence, basis, etc.? I thought the point here was the fact that column vectors ($2\times 1$ matrices) are vectors and row vectors ($1\times 2$ matrices) are linear mappings. But there is a one-to-one correspondence between these two spaces — indeed, a linear isomorphism from one to the other.